# How to paste text into UITextView in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have a UITextView and i want to paste text into that UITextView with button's click event.

You know , when i click a button , the copied text from anywhere paste into that UITextView.

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
MsgtextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",MsgtextView.text,pasteboard.string;
}
```

Check this

Comment: Hi,It's paste just one time.I want to do like TextEdit paste function.Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `TextEdit paste function`. Please be more specific

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I mean , when we paste with Command + V in OSX TextEdit, The paste texts are paste again and again.I mean over and over paste text. Sorry for my bad english. Can i do like that?

Comment: Check my updated answer. It will replace the text like your requirement. The text will copy over and over

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [UIPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    textView.text = pasteboard.string;
```